# Summoning Bitbucket personal repo to Careers profile does not link

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

We have an option to link our personal repositories to our profile but when I try to link my personal Bitbucket repository to my profile - it does not show a link to my repository.

This feature was working fine 2-3 weeks back. Recently something has changed due to which the link to the personal repository is not showing up.

Comment: We now only link to public repos, was the repo you're trying to link private?

Comment: @mythz, yes it is a private repository! That feature was very helpful in letting viewers of your profile also view your private Bitbucket repository. Any idea why this has been removed?

Comment: Including private repos was an oversight. We don't want to list anything on a public CV that's not publically visible.

Answer (score 4):

Allowing listing of private repositories was initially an oversight.

This has now been corrected where we no longer list anything on a public CV that's not publicly visible.

Comment: Actually my profile is not public. So in my case it makes sense to be able to link my non-public repository to a non-public profile.

Comment: Right, we maintain the same behavior for hidden profiles also